# Strange arrows in Firefox Bookmarks Toolbar

Tags: firefox, toolbar

There are a strange set of arrows on my Bookmarks Toolbar.

[image]

The underlying bookmark has nothing to do with it. Even if I delete the bookmark, the arrows still remain.

I am using Firefox 3.6.13 on Ubuntu 10.10. I haven't installed any new extensions or themes.

How can I get rid of these arrows?

Comment: sounds like this isn't a software development question. Your question will be migrated soon to SuperUser.com, where it'll be answered well, I'm sure.

Comment: ah! sorry about that. I just realized it, and posted it myself on SuperUser.com. Thanks.

Comment: Strange ... I am not able to see my question on superuser.com ... Either the one I posted nor the one you migrated ...

Answer (score 0):

These look like the insertion arrows used for dropping links onto the bookmarks toolbar. They should only appear while you are dragging over the toolbar.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. The problem was solved using a suggestion on the Firefox forum on Mozilla by starting Firefox in safe mode. There were no arrows in safe mode. After that the arrows disappeared in normal mode too. But haven't figured out as to why they appeared, because I did not add anything to the toolbar recently.